# Performing DTM compression using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, dem, compression

I have a set of 32-bit TIFF files of DTM data (50 sm) and I need to save them as 16-bit.

In order to save some space, I compressed them using LZW algorith and saved as 16 bit tiffs using Arcpy.

But I see that the precision of height of compressed DTM is not preserved.

Is there a way to preserve it?

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Venera_Workflow\COMpression_TEST\TEST_uncompressed_input"
rasList = arcpy.ListRasters()
outWS = r"D:\Venera_Workflow\COMpression_TEST\TEST_Output_LZW"
arcpy.env.compression = "LZW"
for ras in rasList:
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(ras, os.path.join(outWS, ras, ), "", "", "", "NONE", "NONE", "16_BIT_SIGNED")
```

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

16 bit signed integers can only store whole numbers between -32768 to 32767.

Either keep in 32 bit floating point (and compress) or multiply by 10 before saving to 16 bit int to keep 1 decimal place,  ie 483.41 becomes 4834.